# how to save to database with a column has same values?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database

i want to save 2 kind of values into the database. The first column is "subject" and second is "teacher". For one subject there are many different teachers names. So for example, how can i add "John","Mary","Tom","Lena" with "subject "Math" ?

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=school', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$name=???
$subject="Math";
   $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO teacher (name,subject) VALUES (:name,:subject)");
   $statement->bindParam(':name',$name);
   $statement->bindParam(':subject',$subject);
   $statement->execute();
```

Comment: Normalization dictates every row should be a teacher name (or id) to one subject (or subject id). So if you want John to teach 3 subjects he must be entered into your table 3 times and if you have 3 teachers that teach math, all 3 teachers must have separate rows.

Comment: separately insert each teacher paired to the subject, use can use a loop, just prepare once

Comment: its is not advisable to store multiple values in the same row for a column. What you can do here is insert multiple entries with subject and a single name assigned to it. that way if you want to retrieve all the names for the subject, you can retrieve it easily.

Comment: take note though that if you're going to insert thousands of row, it will be impractical to use a loop and execute each row, you're better of creating a single prepared statement (although it will be a little bit more complex than what you have right now)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a one-to-many relationship. A subject can have many teachers while a teacher can belong to many subjects.

A teachers table could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE teachers (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    teacher varchar(255),
    subject_id int 
)
```

While the subject table will be like so:

```
CREATE TABLE subjects (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    subject varchar(255),
)
```

---

Now having this relationship you can join the 2 tables to get what you need.

```
SELECT * FROM subjects s LEFT JOIN teachers t on s.id = t.subject_id
```

This approach is fairly standard and will normalize your database to some degree.

---

I recommend you do some reading regarding relationships, while the articles I recommend are mostly google-d, I'm sure you can find some that are more complex:

- https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561
- http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/56738/one-to-one-one-to-many-table-relationships-in-sql-server/

Also read about database atomicity - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)

Answer (score 0):

If `$math` is an array with names you can insert them like this in your database with a `foreach`

```
 $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=school', 'root', '');
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO teacher (name,subject) VALUES (?,?)";
            try {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                foreach ($subject as $i => $subjects) {
                    $stmt->execute([$subjects, $math[$i]]);
                }
            } catch (\PDOException $e)
```